# non-static method setPrzechowaj(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced froma a static context

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [non static method cannot be referenced from static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089826/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-static-context)

hey i have problem with JDialogForm. I have created it using netbeans 6.8. That JDialogForm have textfield and button below it. and here is some code...

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       String sciezka = jTextField1.getText();
       if (sciezka.length() > 0)
       {
          Zmienne_pomocnicze.setPrzechowaj(sciezka);
       }
   }
```

Now i want to copy that string "sciezka" to my main window but if I do it like this

```
public class Zmienne_pomocnicze {

public String n;
public void setPrzechowaj (String neew)
{
   n = neew;
}
public String getPrzechowaj ()
{
   return n;
}

}
```

i get error in jButton1: non-static method setPrzechowaj(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced froma a static context
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Zmienne_pomocnicze.setPrzechowaj(sciezka);
```

Here you are calling a method directly by classname without instantiating the class. This requires the method to be `static`, i.e.:

```
public static void setPrzechowaj (String neew)
{
   n = neew;
}
```

But you usually just want to create a reuseable **instance** of the class and call the method on it so that this variable/behaviour doesn't get shared/applied among all existing instances of the class.

```
Zmienne_pomocnicze zp = new Zmienne_pomocnicze();
zp.setPrzechowaj(sciezka);
```

---

**See also:**

- [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)