# non static method cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, oop, static

The code below occurs in the main class of a package I'm trying to create. It references objects and methods from a helper class called Journey. At the call of the `journeyCost` method in the line marked by stars I get a "non static method cannot be referenced from static context" error. This has confused me as I was under the impression that the Journey object "thisJourney", created in the second line, constitutes an instance of the class and thus means the context is not static. Thanks in advance, Seany.

```
public boolean journey(int date, int time, int busNumber, int journeyType){
        Journey thisJourney = new Journey(date, time, busNumber, journeyType);

        if (thisJourney.isInSequence(date, time) == false)
        {
            return false;            
        }
        else
        {
            Journey.updateCurrentCharges(date);

            thisJourney.costOfJourney = Journey.journeyCost(thisJourney);***** 
            Journey.dayCharge = Journey.dayCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
            Journey.weekCharge = Journey.weekCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
            Journey.monthCharge = Journey.monthCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;

            Balance = Balance - thisJourney.costOfJourney;
            jArray.add(thisJourney);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post (again...) the whole stack trace :P

Answer (score 5):

The error means that you are trying to call a non static method in a static way, like maybe this one:

```
 Journey.journeyCost(thisJourney);
```

Is `journeyCost()` declared static? Don't you mean instead `thisJourney.journeyCost()`?

Plus you should use getters and setters to modify and access your member variables, so instead of:

```
Journey.dayCharge = ...
```

you should have

```
Journey.setDayCharge(Journey.getDayCharge() + thisJourney.getCostOfJourney());
```

(`setDayCharge` and `getDayCharge` need to be static in this case)

Answer (score 3):

change

```
Journey.journeyCost(....)
```

to

```
thisJourny.journyCost(...........)
```

your **journyCost** is a non-static method of **Journy** clss, so you have to invoke this method through its object which is **thisJourny**

using the class name, you can only access **static members** or can invoke **static methods** of that class.

Answer (score 3):

All of these lines needs to be changed.  Unless you are really trying to change all future Journey Charges with your last three lines(and that would be assuming those are static values)

```
thisJourney.costOfJourney = thisJourney.journeyCost();//dont know why you are passing the journey object to this method.
Journey.dayCharge = Journey.dayCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
Journey.weekCharge = Journey.weekCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
Journey.monthCharge = Journey.monthCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
```

Those last three lines still need work, I dont know why you are trying to modify the static variable. Try this instead if you just want to set the charges of `thisJourney`

```
thisJourney.dayCharge = Journey.dayCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
thisJourney.weekCharge = Journey.weekCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
thisJourney.monthCharge = Journey.monthCharge + thisJourney.costOfJourney;
```

Although even with that the charge values should be some constant.  You really shouldnt be mixing a static class and instance class of the same type, while interchanging their uses.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the method journeyCost(Journey journey) should be static ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenener you use Journey.someMethod(), someMethod is a static method. "Journey" is in the static context. thisJourney is in the non-static context, because it is an instance. Therefore, you should use

```
    thisJourney.updateCurrentCharges(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `journeyCost` is non-static; so it's an instance method and it requires an instance of `Journey` to get executed. The sentence `Journey.journeyCost(thisJourney);` is invoking the method in a static way, and its expecting that your method is a class-level method (or static).

So, you can make your `journeyCost` method static for your call to work:

```
public static boolean journey(int date, int time, int busNumber, int journeyType)
```

Or try invoking the method from a proper instance:

```
Journey aJourneyInstance = new Journey();
thisJourney.costOfJourney = aJourneyInstance.journeyCost(thisJourney);
```